# How can I use a for loop to name my images with 0 digit placeholders?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have around 150 images that I am downloading and uploading through a for loop. I am also naming each one. I have named them according the whatever my i value is at the moment that the image is uploaded, but that only gives me the exact digits of the i value. I need three digits for every name.

For example, I need 001.png, 002.png,... 123.png, 124.png... etc. But instead, I get 1.png, 2.png... 123.png, 124.png... etc.

My code is here:

```
var n = 4  
func addCards(urlString:String, numberString:String) {
    let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
    let urlRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)

    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(urlRequest, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), completionHandler: {
        response, data, error in

        var image = UIImage(data: data)

        let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
        let imageFile = PFFile(name: "XY\(n)_\(numberString)", data:imageData)

        var cardUpload = PFObject(className:"Cards")
        cardUpload["Image"] = imageFile
        cardUpload["Expansion"] = "XY\(n)"
        cardUpload["Number"] = "XY_\(n)_\(numberString)"

        //THIS (Number) IS THE LINE THAT NAMES MY FILES    

        cardUpload.save()
    })
}

for var i = 1; i < 151; i++ {
    addCards("http://image.com/image\(i)", "\(i)")
}
```

Comment: do a checking for i: if i < 10, image name = i prepend "00", else if i < 100, image name = i prepend "0", else image name = i

Comment: In Objective-C you would use `%03i` as the format specifier. What's the Swift equivalent?

Comment: This is unrelated to your problem, but you can make your loop a little more Swifty with `for i in 1..<151 { ... }`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to format your string to have 3 digits instead of just using the index (which is an unformatted Int) so:

```
String(format: "%03d.png", i)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the format string "%03d" to get numbers with three digits and leading zeros.

```
for myInt in 1...150 {
  println(String(format: "%03d", myInt))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm a big fan of using Cocoa's formatter classes. In your case, I'd use `NSNumberFormatter`, which is great for forming all kinds of strings from numbers. Try this code out -- it outputs a list of filenames, from **001.png** to **150.png**:

```
let threeDigitFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
threeDigitFormatter.minimumIntegerDigits = 3

for imageNumber in 1...150 {
  let formattedImageNumber = threeDigitFormatter.stringFromNumber(imageNumber)!
  let filename = "\(formattedImageNumber).png"
  println(filename)
}
```

Comment: This is probably a case where you don't want to use `NSNumberFormatter` unless the OP actually wants localized filenames.